# Apache commons Fileutils

Tags: java, apache-commons

I downloaded apache commons FileUtils to perform a copy directory and added them under libraries in eclipse as well. When I say `Fileutils.copyDirectory(s,d)` as give below eclipse says " Multiple markers at this line -Syntax error on token "(", delete this token 
-Syntax error on token ")", delete this token". Can someone help

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

Public class b {

    File s = new file("C://Tom//eso");         
    File d = new file("C://Tom//pos");

    FileUtils.copyDirectory(s,d);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class B {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File s = new File("C:/Tom/eso");         
        File d = new File("C:/Tom/pos");
        FileUtils.copyDirectory(s,d);
    }

}
```

There are several errors in your code:

- Classes start with an uppercase char - it's `File`, not `file`. And it's `class B`, not `class b` (remember to also rename the file to `B.java`)
- You must not use double `/` chars, just one
- The code must reside inside a method, not at the class level
- It's `public`, not `Public`
- You're not handling exceptions, either throw them or catch them

Comment: There are actually 4 errors, but you found one I missed, cheers +1

Comment: @MadProgrammer found them! :)

Comment: Thanks. Now I get, the same error  Multiple markers at this line -Syntax error on token "(", delete this token -Syntax error on token ")", delete this token and also Unhandled excepton type IOException

Comment: @user1815823 The example by Óscar compiles just fine for me

Comment: @user1815823 if this answer was helpful for you, please don't forget to accept it by clicking on the check mark to its left

Answer (score 1):

```
File s = new file("C://Tom//eso");  
File d = new file("C://Tom//pos");
```

`file` should be capitalized. It should be `new File(...`.

Side note: Usually for windows the path looks like `C:\\Tom\\eso`, you have forward-slashes instead of backward.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call a method outside of the body of a method...try something more along the lines of;

```
public class b {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        File s = new File("C:/Tom/eso");         
        File d = new File("C:/Tom/pos");

        try {
            FileUtils.copyDirectory(s,d);
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }
}
```

Just to highlight...

- `Public` should be `public`
- `file` should be `File`
- `//` should be either `/` or `\\` (most people prefer `/`)
- Execution code must be executed from the context of a method or static init section

I'd also recommend that you take the time to learn the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) as well as have a read through the tutorials under the [Trails Covering the Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) section

Answer (score 0):

Two errors.
First

```
File s = new file("C://Tom//eso");         
File d = new file("C://Tom//pos");
```

should be

```
File s = new File("C://Tom//eso");         
File d = new File("C://Tom//pos");
```

Second

```
FileUtils.copyDirectory(s,d);
```

should in main method.